# Errno::EACCES creating rails project using Docker Rails image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I'm trying to use the official [Rails image for Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/rails/) to create my development environment and after creating the container using `docker build -t my-rails-app .` I tried to bootstrap the new app using this command:

```
docker run -it --rm --user "$(id -u):$(id -g)" -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app rails rails new --skip-bundle webapp
```

And got this error:

```
      create
/usr/locfrom /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:253:in `fu_mkdir'ied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/src/app/webapp (Errno::EAC
CES)    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:227:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:225:in `block in mkdir_p'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:211:in `mkdir_p'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:116:in `invoke_with_conflict_check'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:94:in `action'b:49:in `invoke!'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:138:in `create_root'ry'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map''
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'ke_all'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>':55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/bundle/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: `Errno::EACCES` it's about permission, i suggest you to remove user part from command `docker run -it --rm -v "$(pwd)":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app rails rails new webapp `

Comment: You're right. At the first moment I misunderstood your answer and thought you were talking about the /usr folder, but then I realized you were mentioning the --user switch and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: There's still one problem though. I thought that the -v switch with $(pwd) would make the /usr/src/app content visible (synced) in my current host folder. Am I wrong?